# Finding fundamental groups of two spaces.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

What are the fundamental groups of

1. $\Bbb R^3 \setminus \{\rm { circle} \}$.
2. $\Bbb R^3 \setminus \{\rm {two\ disjoint\ circles} \}$.

Please help me in this regard. Thank you very much.

Comment: The stereographic projection of any circle on the sphere not passing through the north pole would be a circle on the complex plane which is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$. Hence $\Bbb R^3 \setminus \{\rm {circle\ not\ passing\ through\ the\ origin } \}$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{\rm {circle} \}$. Hence they have isomorphic fundamental groups.

Comment: $\pi_1 (\Bbb R^3 \setminus \{\rm {circle} \}) \simeq \mathbb Z$.